# QGIS with QuickOSM plugin - results from query not excluded to desired layer

Tags: qgis, quickosm

It would be great if you could help me with the following query. I have been working on a solution, unsucessfully for sometime. My goal is to search for certain geographical features within a specific area (2km) of a point feature. My process is as follows:

- I create a point feature (ESPG: 4326) in QGIS using imported coordinates.
- I then right click > save vector layer as shapefile (change to local CRS, in this case EPSG: 25832) so that the metrics are correct in the following step (change from degrees to kilometres)
- I create a 2 km buffer using Vector > geoprocessing tools > buffer
- using quick OSM plugin I search for a geographical feature e.g. for industrial areas in "layer extent" and use the buffer I previously created as the layer as the input

The problem is that it doesn't return only results inside the buffer, but in the entire map!

[image: 2km buffer area from point feature (purple circle) and the grey areas are the results from the QuickOSM feature]

..........

EDIT - QuickOSM - search "around WKT" as suggested in comments

[image: selected features(in this buildings in the green colour)from "around WKT"]

Comment: Rather than "layer extent" you should use "around" and provide your point coordinate in WKT format (this save you the buffer steep) (dont forget to set the distance value). Alternatively you may try to select your buffer then use "layer extent" with the "only selected features" option but this will extract using the square enclosing your buffer rather than only the buffer area

Comment: @J.R this is a great suggestion. However, for some reason it doesn't select all the features from the selected area. Please see the second picture above. The green shapes are the "buildings" (results from QuickOSM search) but as you can see there are alot of buildings that haven't been selected. 2. Is it also possible to search "around" a WKT using a polygon shape. For example, often I need to search within a buffer area of 3km from 3 nearby point features.